# Why are my items moving at different speeds?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game in python with pygame.

I've made a parent class Items with 4 children.
As far as I can see, they should all be moving at speed 'dx' as defined in the Items class.
However, when I run the program, some of them are much faster than others. It seems to be inconsistent as to which colour items are faster, too.

```
import pygame
from random import randint

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

gravity = 15

# Colours
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
CYAN = (0, 255, 255)


def draw_window():
    WINDOW.fill(WHITE)
    for item in items:
        item.draw_item()
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        clock.tick(FPS)

        for item in items:
            item.movement()

        draw_window()
    pygame.quit()


class Item:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.radius = 10
        self.y = randint(100, 500) + self.radius
        self.dx = -2

    def perform_action(self):
        pass

    def movement(self):
        self.x += self.dx
        if self.x < 0 - WIDTH:
            self.x = WIDTH + randint(0, 300)
            self.y = HEIGHT - 40 - randint(0, 400)

    def draw_item(self, colour):
        pygame.draw.circle(WINDOW, colour, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)


class GravUp(Item):

    def __init__(self, x):
        super().__init__(x)

    def draw_item(self):
        super().draw_item(RED)

    def perform_action(self):
        global gravity
        gravity += 3


class GravDown(Item):

    def __init__(self, x):
        super().__init__(x)

    def draw_item(self):
        super().draw_item(GREEN)


class AgilUp(Item):

    def __init__(self, x):
        super().__init__(x)

    def draw_item(self):
        super().draw_item(CYAN)


item_types = {0: GravUp(WIDTH + randint(0, 500)),
              1: GravDown(WIDTH + randint(0, 500)),
              2: AgilUp(WIDTH + randint(0, 500))}
items = []

for i in range(10):
    items.append(item_types[randint(0, 2)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: there is more than one question here and too many details, however, you have a random function in the movement which could explain the inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Ok I've edited out the extra question. By the random function do you mean the 'if' statement? That's to reset the item if it goes off the screen so in my mind it's still movement related and needs to be checked whenever the movement is checked. Either way I commented it out and the problem persists.

Comment: if is not random, randint is a random integer, check the documentation.

Comment: I thought he meant random as in 'unexpected'. There is no random element in the movement function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your random speed behavior resides within the following lines of code in your program.

```
item_types = {0: GravUp(WIDTH + randint(0, 500)),
              1: GravDown(WIDTH + randint(0, 500)),
              2: AgilUp(WIDTH + randint(0, 500))}

items = []

for i in range(10):
    items.append(item_types[randint(0, 2)])
```

What this bit of code is doing is indeed defining your three colored circles.  Then, it is randomly assigning a number of times (one out of ten ) each circle will be moved and redrawn.

When I added in a print operation within the "draw_item" function and ran the program, I was able to determine the number of drawing/redrawing calls each circle was getting by printing out the item's RGB color value.

```
(0, 255, 0)
(255, 0, 0)
(255, 0, 0)
(255, 0, 0)
(0, 255, 0)
(0, 255, 0)
(0, 255, 255)
(255, 0, 0)
(0, 255, 0)
(0, 255, 255)
```

If you tally up the quantities, the green circle gets four calls to move and redraw, the red circle gets four calls to move and redraw, and the cyan circle gets two calls to move and redraw.  Running this again would probably produce a different mix of calls for each color.

Reviewing your code, I am guessing what you ultimately wanted to do was create ten circles with random colors at random positions.  If that is actually what you want to do, you will need to revise the block of code to derive a random number first, and then based upon that number, populate the item group with the random item type.

I hope that clarifies things.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. I now see that I was initialising the items when I created the dictionary, so only those 3 items were created.

I think I have got it working now with a 'match + case'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When printing out the addresses of the created objects you will see why there are different speeds:

```
<__main__.AgilUp object at 0x0BD30E70>
<__main__.AgilUp object at 0x0BD30E70>
<__main__.GravUp object at 0x0BD30550>
<__main__.AgilUp object at 0x0BD30E70>
<__main__.GravUp object at 0x0BD30550>
<__main__.GravUp object at 0x0BD30550>
<__main__.GravDown object at 0x0BD306F0>
<__main__.GravDown object at 0x0BD306F0>
<__main__.AgilUp object at 0x0BD30E70>
<__main__.AgilUp object at 0x0BD30E70>
```

So you don't have 10 objects, but only three, and 10 random pointers to one of these. In this example, the movement instructions will call 5 times AgilUp, 3 times GravUp and 2 times GravDown.

Redesigning the object creation process should fix the issue.